# Move a WMWare Workstation from an Intel 32-bits to a AMD 64-bits with two proccesors

Tags: vmware-workstation, intel, central-processing-unit

I have moved a VMWare Workstation machine which was created in a 32-bit intel single processor system running VMware workstation 7 to a different system with a 64 bit AMD multiprocessor and running Vmware Workstation 8..

I have read in this website a person with a similar problem but he moved from AMD to Intel, and, according to I have just read, no issues are involved.

In my case, a message appears when I power up the virtual machine in the destination physical host (AMD 64 bits, 2 microprocessors):

"THE VENDOR OF THE PROCESSOR IN THIS VIRTUAL MACHINE IS NOT THE SAME AS THE VENDOR OF THE PROCESSORS IN THE MACHINE ON WHICH THE VIRTUAL MACHINE STATE WAS SAVED. You may attempt to resume this virtual machine , but doing so may result in unpredictable behavior."

Comment: You may run into problems later on if you want to use more than one processor in your VM later on.

Answer (score 1):

You have a snapshot of the VM took when the machine was running. You can not use that snapshot on a different CPU.

You have 2 solutions:

1. You can discard the snapshot
2. you can move back the VM on the old Intel machine, shout it down and then move it back to the destination machine (AMD).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mircea. So, there is no problem in moving a virtual machine from Intel 32bits processors to AMD 64bits processors , or vice cersa? . 

I'll check the snapshots. As far as I remember there were no snapshots in this machine. 

The vm machine is now running in the destination without apparent problems, and there is no snapshots in this machine. Should I check the snapshots in the other machine, in the source host ? . I'll do it and get back here to post what I saw.

Comment: The snapshots taken when the VM is shouted down are fine. Only those taken when the VM was running are not portable. Usually, you can only move 32bit VM from and to a 32bit host. 64bit VM are incompatible with 32bit hosts. Even if they might run, they will run in emulation mode at much slower speed.

Comment: If the VM is running fine, then the VM transfer is ok. It is very important that the guest kernel is fully supporting the new cpu. Reinstall VMware Tools on the guest that was moved.